# Delegate method not working ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I used delegate mehod for pass data between view controllers. This is not working.

```
@protocol PassCountry <NSObject>

@required
- (void) setPickedCountry:(NSString *)pickedCountry;
@end

@interface SelectCountryViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
    id <PassCountry> delegate;
}

@property (copy) NSString *pickedCountry;
@property (retain) id delegate;

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent (NSInteger)component {
    pickedCountry = [self.countries objectAtIndex:row];
}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.countries.count;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[self delegate] setPickedCountry:pickedCountry];
}
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Comment: where u are calling this delegate method, show that code

Comment: where are you setting the delegate, show that code as well

Comment: In destination viewcotroller have you set its obj.delgate=self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  @protocol PassCountry <NSObject>

  @required
   - (void) setPickedCountry:(NSString *)pickedCountry;
   @end

  @interface secondViewViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate,  UIPickerViewDataSource>
  {
      id <PassCountry> delegate;

     IBOutlet UIButton *aButton;
  }

 @property (copy) NSString *pickedCountry;
 @property (assign) id<PassCountry> delegate; // for delegate use assign don't retain

 // in another class you are creating instance of this class

  secondViewViewController *secController = [[secondViewViewController alloc]init];
  secController.delegate = self;//check this added or not
  [self presentViewController:secController animated:YES completion:nil];

  //and implementation of deleagte method  
  - (void) setPickedCountry:(NSString *)pickedCountry
   {
       // do some stuff

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

.h File

```
@protocol delegateTextSize <NSObject>

@optional
 -(void)selectedTextSize:(double)textSize;
@end

@interface CustomFontSizeCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,retain) id delegateTextSize;
-(IBAction)changeSize:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m File

```
-(IBAction)changeSize:(id)sender
{
    [delegateTextSize selectedTextSize:app.selectedFontSize];
}
```

Where to use,

.h File

```
Controller <delegateTextSize>
```

.m File

```
-(void)selectedTextSize:(double)textSize
{
}
```

Hopefully, this will work

Thanks.

Comment: Downvoting for the memory implications that entail the result of a delegated object that is being retained.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, delegate instance can not be retained. 
Secondly, delegate should be synthesized using "@synthesize delegate" before invoke the method [self delegate].